# Donations Used to Provide Legal Support for Fraudster

Tags: halacha, tzedakah-charity, nedarim-shevuot

Can a person who promised to themselves (but did not yet "mail the check") to give charity to a specific Torah organization, not give the tzedakah if they learn the organization is using (at least some of the) donations to provide legal support for a person on trial for crimes that, if he's guilty of them, are also halachic violations?

Is the tzedakha considered a "vow" requiring the person to have to send the donation despite what they now know about the organization?

Comment: Ask your LOR for case specific guidance.

Comment: user3142, let me extend a belated welcome to Mi Yodeya! Please consider [editing your profile](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/edit/3142) to give yourself a name. Also, please consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) to more of the site's features.

Comment: It sounds like there are several questions here that complicate the base question.  Here are some options depending on what you're actually asking:
1. If I promise myself that I will send tzedakah to a particular organization, and then I find out information about that organization that would have discouraged me from making that promise, must I still send that tzedakah?
2. Is it kosher to provide for the legal defense of a person on trial for crimes that...

Comment: (cont'd)... are halakhic violations?
3. If I promise myself that I will send tzedakah to a particular organization, and then I find out that the organization is not acting in a halakhically acceptable way, must I/may I still give?

Comment: ....there are other questions that you might actually be asking. I'm just giving some choices.

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman, I think there's one question here that touches on all of those aspects. I don't see what the problem is. Given that this confluence of issues is plausibly a situation that comes up for people, I don't see the benefit of trying to force an asker to atomize it before it can be answered.

Comment: @IsaacMoses sure, but the OP might get cleaner answers by atomizing.

Comment: I appreciate everyone attempting to understand my question. I asked my Rabbi a few hours ago. His response was that if I made a personal vow to donate before knowing what I know about this organization, I still should send the donation but specify that the money should not be used for the legal fund.

Comment: @JeffreyLevine Care to post this comment as an answer?

Comment: Thank you Charles for your comments. I reposted my previous post as an answer as you suggested. Shana Tova.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I appreciate everyone attempting to understand my question. Thankfully, when I asked my Rabbi a couple of weeks ago he understood the question perfectly. His response was that if I made a personal vow to donate before knowing what I know now about this organization, I still should send the donation but specify that the money not be used for the legal fund. (By the way, the rabbi stated that if I made the promise public I would also have to send the donation using the same stipulation.) Shana Tova.

Comment: You are welcone Double AA